# Arduino - control a motor with MKS V1.5 Board

Tags: arduino

I am new to Arduino.
I would like to control a motor which is connect to MKS Base V1.5 Board.
The motor will be connect via E1 Motor output.
I would like to see a Arduino sample code to understand how can i control the 
direction of the motor and the speed.
many thanks if anyone can help with this.

Thank you
Hagai

Comment: Have you installed the Board files for the MKS Base board?
If you have you will find an example for motor control in file>examples.

Comment: Thanks.
Where can I find those files and where can I find an instruction how to install them in the environment ?

Comment: My apologies, it seems like MKS base board does not have Board files for Arduino, and you are supposed to compile it's firmware for Arduino Mega board.

Obviously there won't be any examples there.

Comment: thanks
anyone know if MKS can work with Stepper class ?

Answer (score 0):

You can download the U8Glib for the MKS board, from this page
http://kookye.com/2016/05/30/mks-1-4-3d-printer-board-marlin-firmware-installation-guide/

It was meant for MKS Board 1.4, but I think it should work with this one as well.

The library contains an example for motor rotation.

I hope this helps, good luck.

Comment: Thank you. I will try this.